# How to mark/Unmark image in UIGridView in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView) as 2 Column is there and there are list of array in which images kept. Now I want to compare two car so that i have to mark any two images in `UIGridView`. So that I can compare any two cars. i am not fully aware of GridView.

Compare should be happened when red navigation button clicked.

My Code is Given Below:

```
   CarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [CarArray addObject:@"image.png"];
   [CarArray addObject:@"car-image.png"];
   [CarArray addObject:@"mercy.png"];
   [CarArray addObject:@"lanbo.png"];

}

- (CGFloat) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid widthForColumnAt:(int)columnIndex
{
    return 160;
}

- (CGFloat) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid heightForRowAt:(int)rowIndex
{
    return 200;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfColumnsOfGridView:(UIGridView *) grid
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfCellsOfGridView:(UIGridView *) grid
{
    return [CarArray count];
}

- (UIGridViewCell *) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid cellForRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)columnIndex
{
    Cell *cell = (Cell *)[grid dequeueReusableCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] init];
    }

    cell.thumbnail.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[CarArray objectAtIndex:(rowIndex*2+columnIndex)]];

    return cell;
}

- (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)colIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%d, %d clicked", rowIndex, colIndex);
    CarDetailViewController *servicesViewController_obj=[[CarDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CarDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:servicesViewController_obj animated:YES];

}
```

i also want to implement mark and unmark so i can move further.[image: i have to show This mark sign (right symbol in image below)]

Comment: can i give an answer in some other way other then grid view. In some simple way

Comment: @CharanGiri yeah sure.....pls

Comment: @CharanGiri but i cannot change or remove grid view so make sure that

Comment: Which sample code are you using? There is no control in Objective C called UIGridView as of now.

Comment: @PiyushDubey from github um using it

Comment: @RahulShrimali Check my answer. It is for mark/unmark the image.

Comment: @RahulShrimali There are thousands of sample code on github. You should mention the link of sample code in your question.

Comment: @PiyushDubey https://codeload.github.com/tanin47/UIGridView/zip/master

Comment: @RahulShrimali My assumption was correct. Check my answer.

Comment: @CharanGiri http://pastie.org/8597082

Comment: @RahulShrimali Hi are you there? are you able to select more than 1 car?

Comment: @CharanGiri yeah i m here bro can u please help me check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992710/change-gui-when-select-ios6-in-xcode-5

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using this [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView) sample code.
 I have done some changes in sample code for your requirement. Please follow steps to change images in grid view:-
1. In **UIGridViewDelegate.h:-** 
 Change the optional method 
`- (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)columnIndex;` 
 to 
 `- (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)columnIndex gridViewCell:(UIGridViewCell *)gridViewCell;` 
 2. In **UIGridView.m:-** 
 Change this code

```
- (IBAction) cellPressed:(id) sender
{
    UIGridViewCell *cell = (UIGridViewCell *) sender;
    [uiGridViewDelegate gridView:self didSelectRowAt:cell.rowIndex AndColumnAt:cell.colIndex];
}
```

with

```
- (IBAction) cellPressed:(id) sender
{
    UIGridViewCell *cell = (UIGridViewCell *) sender;
    [uiGridViewDelegate gridView:self didSelectRowAt:cell.rowIndex AndColumnAt:cell.colIndex gridViewCell:cell];
}
```

3. In **RootViewController.m:-** 
 Add this code

```
- (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)colIndex gridViewCell:(UIGridViewCell *)gridViewCell
{
    NSLog(@"%d, %d clicked", rowIndex, colIndex);

    Cell *cellTemp = (Cell *)gridViewCell;
    UIImage *imgT = cellTemp.thumbnail.image;


    // Change the image names according to your images
    if (imgT == [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_picture.png"]) // If first image is there
    {
        // Replace the image with second image
        cellTemp.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        // Replace the image with first image
        cellTemp.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_picture.png"];
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the warnings?

Comment: instance method not found -gridviewcellforrow at index path in uiGridView.m

Comment: 2nd is also instance method not found -gridviewdidselectrow returntyps default to id

Comment: @implementation carviewcontroller : Method:cellforrowat:andcolumnat and gridviewcell not implemented

Comment: The above code is working fine for me. Try to check warning at your end.

Answer (score 0):

// Call this method in some button action so that you will get selected cars tag value
   //  [self getSelectedCars]; and also

```
@interface ViewController ()   
{   
UIImageView *thumbnailView;   
NSMutableArray *selectedThumbsArray;  
NSArray *dumyimages;  
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
dumyimages=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept@2x.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa@2x.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"], nil];
selectedThumbsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0", nil];
int imagesCount =0;
int yAxis =50;
int xAxis =50;
for (int i=0; i<dumyimages.count; i++) {

    thumbnailView =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    thumbnailView.frame=CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, 120, 120);
    thumbnailView.tag=i+10;
    thumbnailView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    thumbnailView.image=dumyimages[i];
    xAxis=xAxis+125;

    imagesCount=imagesCount+1;
    if (imagesCount==2) {
        xAxis=50;
        yAxis=yAxis+125;
        imagesCount=0;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:thumbnailView];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [thumbnailView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

}
- (void)handleLongPress:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
NSLog(@"Gesture tag is,%i", gestureRecognizer.view.tag-10) ;
int indexofThumb =gestureRecognizer.view.tag-10;

if ([selectedThumbsArray[indexofThumb] intValue]==0 ) {
    [selectedThumbsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexofThumb withObject:@"1"];

    thumbnailView=(UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:indexofThumb];
    thumbnailView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
}
else
{
    [selectedThumbsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexofThumb withObject:@"0"];
    thumbnailView=(UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:indexofThumb];
    thumbnailView.image=dumyimages[indexofThumb];
}

}
- (void)getSelectedCars
{
for (int i=0; i<selectedThumbsArray.count; i++) {

    if ([selectedThumbsArray[i] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSLog(@"indexes are ------>%d",i); // here list of index of selected images will come you can use accordingly
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use your current code "Grid view" means

To get the indexes of image views

```
- (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)colIndex
{
NSLog(@"%d, %d clicked", rowIndex, colIndex);
int index =(1*rowIndex)+rowIndex+colIndex; // here 1 is the max no of columns-1. 
NSLog(@"arrayindex is----->%d",index);
}
```